# Excel: Index match multiple columns

Tags: excel, search

I am trying to make a formula like index match but I want to search for a number in multiple columns and show the header of this number.

I have found on the internet a formula which is working but when for example I search number 1234, it matches with the number 51234 which includes the 1234.

=INDEX($AB$3:$AQ$3;1;SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(D6;$AB$3:$AQ$494)));COLUMN(A:P);99^99);1))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvVHH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdufF.png)

In the first image there are numbers that I would like to search in the array that second image shows. For example I would like to know in which category the number 4027 in column D belongs to.

Any ideas how to make this formula search for the exact number or another formula maybe;

Thanks

Comment: please mock up some data that shows the issue and include the actual formula that causes the issue.

Comment: And, please, use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63019329/edit) button to do so!

Comment: If you need more info let me know